# PHP Blank output

Tags: php

My php code is:

```
<?php

class Markov {
protected $arr0;
protected $arr1;
protected $arr2;
public $n;
public $p00;
public $p01;
public $p02;
public $p10;
public $p11;
public $p12;
public $p20;
public $p21;
public $p22;
public function __construct($p)
{
    $arr0=new SplFixedArray(3);
    $arr1=new SplFixedArray(3);
    $arr2=new SplFixedArray(3);
    $this->n=$p;
 for($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
 {
     $arr0[$i]=0;
     $arr1[$i]=0;
     $arr2[$i]=0;
 }
}
public function calculate_constants($first,$last)
{
if($this->n>1)
{
 for($j=0; $j<count($first); $j++)
 {
     if($first[$j]>=0 && $first[$j]<3)
     {
       if($last[$j]>=0 && $last[$j]<3)
       {
           $this->arr.$first[$j][$last[$j]]+=1;

       }
     }
 }
}
    else
    {
        for($k=0; $k<3; $k++)
        {
          $this->p0.$k=$this->arr0[$k]/($this->arr0[0]+$this->arr0[1]+$this->arr0[2]);
        }
        for($k=0; $k<3; $k++)
        {
            $this->p1.$k=$this->arr1[$k]/($this->arr1[0]+$this->arr1[1]+$this->arr1[2]);
        }
        for($k=0; $k<3; $k++)
        {
            $this->p2.$k=$this->arr2[$k]/($this->arr2[0]+$this->arr2[1]+$this->arr2[2]);
        }
    }
    $this->n-=1;
}
   public function display_constants()
   {
   echo $this->p00.'\n'.$this->p01.'\n'.$this->p02;
   echo $this->p10.'\n'.$this->p11.'\n'.$this->p12;
   echo $this->p20.'\n'.$this->p21.'\n'.$this->p22;
   }
   }
   $m= new Markov(5);
   $m->calculate_constants(array(0,1,2),array(1,2,1));
   $m->display_constants();
   ?>
```

In this my variable values p00,p01 etc are not changing even though I have used it in functions to calculate their value. Please Help me to correct the code so that the required output can be obtained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you actually want but you will not have any error now. One issue is that you haven't assigned values in array $arr0 but you are using it, I tried assign in for loop for getting ride from errors.

```
<?php
class Markov {
    protected $arr0;
    protected $arr1;
    protected $arr2;
    public $n;
    public $p00;
    public $p01;
    public $p02;
    public $p10;
    public $p11;
    public $p12;
    public $p20;
    public $p21;
    public $p22;
    public function __construct($p)
    {
        $this->arr0=new SplFixedArray(3);
        $this->arr1=new SplFixedArray(3);
        $this->arr2=new SplFixedArray(3);
        $this->n = $p;
        for($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
        {
            $this->arr0[$i]=0;
            $this->arr1[$i]=0;
            $this->arr2[$i]=0;
        }
    }
    public function calculate_constants($first,$last)
    {
        if($this->n > 1){
            for($j=0; $j<count($first); $j++){
                if($first[$j]>=0 && $first[$j]<3){
                    if($last[$j]>=0 && $last[$j]<3){
                        $var = 'arr'.$first[$j];
                        $this->{$var}[$last[$j]] += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            for($k=0; $k<3; $k++) {
                $this->{'p0'.$k}=$this->arr0[$k]/($this->arr0[0]+$this->arr0[1]+$this->arr0[2]);
            }
            for($k=0; $k<3; $k++) {
                $this->{'p1'.$k}=$this->arr1[$k]/($this->arr1[0]+$this->arr1[1]+$this->arr1[2]);
            }
            for($k=0; $k<3; $k++) {
                $this->{'p2'.$k}=$this->arr2[$k]/($this->arr2[0]+$this->arr2[1]+$this->arr2[2]);
            }
        }
        $this->n -= 1;
    }
    public function display_constants() {
        echo $this->p00.'\n'.$this->p01.'\n'.$this->p02;
        echo $this->p10.'\n'.$this->p11.'\n'.$this->p12;
        echo $this->p20.'\n'.$this->p21.'\n'.$this->p22;
   }
}
$m= new Markov(5);
$m->calculate_constants(array(0,1,2),array(1,2,1));
$m->display_constants();
?>
```

As your else condition is not executing, $p00, $p01....etc always be blank. You can move for loop to other function:

```
public function display_constants() {
        for($k=0; $k<3; $k++) {
            $this->{'p0'.$k}=$this->arr0[$k]/($this->arr0[0]+$this->arr0[1]+$this->arr0[2]);
        }
        for($k=0; $k<3; $k++) {
            $this->{'p1'.$k}=$this->arr1[$k]/($this->arr1[0]+$this->arr1[1]+$this->arr1[2]);
        }
        for($k=0; $k<3; $k++) {
            $this->{'p2'.$k}=$this->arr2[$k]/($this->arr2[0]+$this->arr2[1]+$this->arr2[2]);
        }
        echo $this->p00.'<br>'.$this->p01.'<br>'.$this->p02;
        echo $this->p10.'<br>'.$this->p11.'<br>'.$this->p12;
        echo $this->p20.'<br>'.$this->p21.'<br>'.$this->p22;
   }
```

Comment: New Error coming:
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\Wnmp\html\MarkovChain\Markov.php on line 42

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\Wnmp\html\MarkovChain\Markov.php on line 42

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\Wnmp\html\MarkovChain\Markov.php on line 42
\n\n\n\n\n\n

Comment: Line must be $this->{$var}[$last[$j]] += 1; So if you are trying to access $arr0[1] but your array have $arr[0] only then you will get this error. You have to sort this out according your need. What you actually wants to do?

Comment: I have initialised arr0[0],arr0[1] and arr0[2] with 0 value

Comment: First of all when you call $m->calculate_constants(array(0,1,2),array(1,2,1)); only if condition runs not else because $this->n is 5 so how you will get any value in $p00,$p01....etc. It will be blank always.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following on top of your file (below the `<?php` tag)

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

Blank page usually means an error, but those are hidden by default.

Comment: I am getting the following warnings and errors:

Notice: Undefined property: Markov::$arr in C:\Wnmp\html\MarkovChain\Markov.php on line 47

Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in C:\Wnmp\html\MarkovChain\Markov.php on line 47

Notice: Undefined property: Markov::$arr in C:\Wnmp\html\MarkovChain\Markov.php on line 47

Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in C:\Wnmp\html\MarkovChain\Markov.php on line 47

Notice: Undefined property: Markov::$arr in C:\Wnmp\html\MarkovChain\Markov.php on line 47

Comment: at line 47 the value of the array which is getting computed is undefined

Comment: No, it is defined, but it is wrongly defined. It first tells you "Cannot use a scalar value as an array in xxxx" and then throws a notice. Its undefined because of the warning.

Comment: New error coming up:
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\Wnmp\html\MarkovChain\Markov.php on line 42

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\Wnmp\html\MarkovChain\Markov.php on line 42

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\Wnmp\html\MarkovChain\Markov.php on line 42
\n\n\n\n\n\n

Comment: Please sign this as an answer if it solved your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Please set `error_reporting(-1);` and `ini_set('display_errors', true);` in the top of your file.

Comment: I wouldn't put that in your php.ini file ;P